# Python get degrees within nodes

Tags: python, list, networkx

How can I get the degrees from a network graph.

```
list(graph.degree().values())
```

example [0,2,4,1,0,3,2,1,4,0,2,0] and I want just the degrees like.

```
[0,1,2,3,4]
```

is there some kind of function within python or networkx

Comment: Sorry but doesn't `graph,degree()` give you what you want? it'll by default return a dict of all the nodes and their degrees, otherwise you need to pass a bunch of nodes to get the degrees for those nodes

Comment: It's unclear what you're after here, are you wanting just a list of the unique degree values? in which case you can just do `set(graph.degree().values())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only keep unique elements in your list,

Use `set()`

```
mylist = list(graph.degree().values())
unique_elements_list = list(set(mylist))
```

Use `list()`:

```
mylist = list(graph.degree().values())

unique_elements_list = list()

# iterates all elements in mylist
for element in mylist:
    # adds to unique elements list only current
    # element is not included.
    if element not in unique_elements_list:
        unique_elements_list.append(element)
```